# Запятая или тире?

Tags: пунктуация

1) Книгу нашел Я (,/-)  Козанков Дмитрий Александрович. 
2) Я (,/-) Козанков Дмитрий Александрович (,/-) нашЁл книгу. 
Я (,/-) Козанков Дмитрий Александрович (,/-) нашёл кнИгу.

Answer (score 1):

1) Приложение, отнесенное к личному местоимению, обособляется в любой позиции, **но в правилах нет примеров использования тире в этом случае (даже если приложение стоит в конце предложения):**:

Книгу нашел я, Козанков Дмитрий Александрович. Я, Козанков Дмитрий Александрович, нашёл книгу. Книгу нашел я, Козанков Дмитрий Александрович. Я, Козанков Дмитрий Александрович, нашёл книгу.

**Розенталь**: Всегда обособляется приложение при личном местоимении: Ему ли, карлику, тягаться с исполином? (П.); Доктринёр и несколько педант, он любил поучительно наставлять (Герц.);  Вот **оно, объяснение** (Л. Т.).

Логическое выделение отдельных слов не будут влиять на постановку запятых.

2) **Для постановки тире** можно рассмотреть вопрос об **авторской пунктуации** для приложения в середине предложения, применив вставочную конструкцию (**увеличенные паузы, общее понижение тона**): Я - Козанков Дмитрий Александрович - нашЁл эту книгу.

Comment: Вот пример: Вот мы – соучастники сборищ.

Comment: Серж, эта конструкция похожа на простое предложение: мы - подлежащее, соучастники - сказуемое, тире интонационное, авторское. Или что это, назывное предложение?  Для определения нужен полный текст.

Comment: "Козанков Дмитрий Александрович" не поясняет определяемое слово (в данном случае - личное местоимение). Поэтому нет никакой надобности  ставить здесь тире.  Я так думаю.

Answer (score 0):

Корректно:

*Книгу нашел я - Козанков Дмитрий Александрович*.

*Я, Козанков Дмитрий Александрович, нашел книгу.*

Приложение, относящееся к личному местоимению, обособляется в любом случае, вне зависимости от места в предложении. Однако приложения, стоящее в конце предложения, обычно обособляются при помощи тире, а не запятой.

[См: Обособление приложений](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_176)